# How do I center an image on a sheet while printing in Photoshop?

Tags: printing, photoshop-cs5

How do I center an image on a sheet of paper while printing in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

Select the background layer in the layers tab, goto the menu *Layer > Align Layers to Selection* - then choose your desired alignment.